# SWI-Prolog: Using Threading with Mutex locks

Tags: multithreading, prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to get used to Prolog's threading library. I know it's based upon C's threads implementation, and I'm fairly familiar with that. A simple example of the usage of mutex locks in C is that of doing some mathematical operations on a shared resource, since not mutex locking the atomic instructions that modify the original shared resource leads to random behavior caused by a race conditions. I'm trying to write the same example in Prolog, but my program simply hangs and I'm not quite sure how to use a shared resource parameter the same way I would in C. Here's my code:

```
mutex_create(mtx1).

add_2(X,D):-number(X),mutex_lock(mtx1),D is X+2,mutex_unlock(mtx1).

sub_3(Y,D):-number(Y),mutex_lock(mtx1),D is Y-3,mutex_unlock(mtx1).

main(M):-
    thread_create(add_2(M,A),ID_1),
    thread_create(sub_3(A,F),ID_2),
    thread_join(ID_1),
    thread_join(ID_2),
    writeln(F).
```

Using trace, I can see that my code gets hung up when it tries to join the ID_1 thread that uses the add_2 predicate, but I am not sure why:

```
[trace]  ?- main(5).
   Call: (8) main(5) ? creep
^  Call: (9) thread_create(add_2(5, _10024), _10044) ? creep
^  Exit: (9) thread_create(user:add_2(5, _10024), <thread>(18,0x559ab291d1e0)) ? 
   Call: (1) add_2(5, _10) ? creep
^  Call: (9) thread_create(sub_3(_10024, _10036), _10056) ? creep
^  Exit: (9) thread_create(user:sub_3(_10024, _10036), <thread>(19,0x559ab291d730)) ? 
   Call: (1) sub_3(_8, _10) ? creep
   Call: (9) thread_join(<thread>(18,0x559ab291d1e0)) ? creep
```

What I'd like to have happen is that each thread runs and eventually what my main(M) predicate prints out every time is 4.

Comment: You probably need to `mutex_unlock` instead of `mutex_lock` at the end of `add_2` and `sub_3`

Comment: Ah yeah, silly syntax mistake on my part. However, even when fixing the second lock call to be unlock, the program still hangs. A call to trace reveals the same bug, and the program still hangs. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Your example cannot really execute concurrently because `add_2` must complete before `sub_3` can execute. Note that `number(Y)` in `sub_3` will fail if Y is uninstantiated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `mutex_create/1` predicate instead of trying to define a fact for it. Try:

```
:- initialization(mutex_create(mtx1)).

add_2(X,D):-number(X),mutex_lock(mtx1),D is X+2,mutex_unlock(mtx1).

sub_3(Y,D):-number(Y),mutex_lock(mtx1),D is Y-3,mutex_unlock(mtx1).

main(M):-
    thread_create(add_2(M,A),ID_1),
    thread_create(sub_3(A,F),ID_2),
    thread_join(ID_1),
    thread_join(ID_2),
    writeln(F).
```

But note that calling `main/1` will still fail as explained in the comments by @gusbro.

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to use setup_call_cleanup/3 to perform the mutex/unmutex ops? (And is it time for [Software Transactional Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) in Prolog? It would make sense.)

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog, a possible solution is:

```
main(Number) :-
    flag(shared, _, Number), % Number is a shared data
    setup_call_cleanup(
        mutex_create(Mutex, [alias(my_mutex)]),
        (   thread_create(add_2(shared), ID_1),
            thread_create(sub_3(shared), ID_2),
            thread_join(ID_1),
            thread_join(ID_2) ),
        mutex_destroy(Mutex) ),
    flag(shared, NewNumber, NewNumber),
    writeln(shared: NewNumber).

add_2(Shared) :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
        mutex_lock(my_mutex),
        (   flag(Shared, Number, Number),
            NewNumber is Number + 2,
            flag(Shared, _, NewNumber) ),
        mutex_unlock(my_mutex) ),
    writeln(Number -> NewNumber).

sub_3(Shared) :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
        mutex_lock(my_mutex),
        (   flag(Shared, Number, Number),
            NewNumber is Number - 3,
            flag(Shared, _, NewNumber) ),
        mutex_unlock(my_mutex) ),
    writeln(Number -> NewNumber).
```

Result:

```
?- main(5).
5->7
7->4
shared:4
true.
```

**P.S.** According to the documentation "*Prolog threads have their own stacks and only share the Prolog heap: predicates, records, flags and other global non-backtrackable data.*"

Comment: Ah I see! So essentially unless it’s explicitly flagged, prolog’s threads are always going to be acting on differently instantiated variables from my main thread, and do not act the same way wrt shared resources the way C or C++ threads would. What exactly does setup_call_cleanup/1 do in this case?

Comment: The goal ```setup_call_cleanup(Setup,Goal,Cleanup)``` calls ```(once(Setup), Goal)```. If ```Setup``` succeeds, ```Cleanup``` will be called exactly once after ```Goal``` is finished: either on failure, deterministic success, commit, or an exception.

Answer (score 1):

thread_create/2 creates a copy of the given goal, a variable
binding from the slave threads to the master thread will
never be returned. Or as the documentation reads:

> The Goal argument is copied to the new Prolog engine. This implies that further instantiation of this term in either thread does not have consequences for the other thread: Prolog threads do not share data from their stacks.

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=thread_create/3

So @slago's solution might reflect the OPs intention. But it should be noted that SWI-Prolog has [with_mutex/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=with_mutex/2). Using this meta predicate the code by @slago can be simplified:

```
add_2(Shared) :-
    with_mutex(my_mutex,
        (   flag(Shared, Number, Number),
            NewNumber is Number + 2,
            flag(Shared, _, NewNumber) )),
    writeln(Number -> NewNumber).

sub_3(Shared) :-
    with_mutex(
        (   flag(Shared, Number, Number),
            NewNumber is Number - 3,
            flag(Shared, _, NewNumber) )),
    writeln(Number -> NewNumber).
```

with_mutex/2 is suitable when the second argument is semi-deterministic. Jekejeke Prolog has with_lock/2, which allows a second argument that is multi.